# Using slick (jquery plugin) with dojo

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dojo, websphere-commerce

We are developing a web application (based on Websphere Commerce) with Dojo 1.8 and Dijit as underlying javascript framework. Now I would like to use the slick jquery plugin (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick).

I read some examples on how to include JQuery together with Dojo, but they are quite old (in our environment dojo uses $()) and I did not get it to work with a JQuery plugin, slick in this case. Is there an example how to do it?

I tried it here, with a Dojo environment including JQuery and slick:
https://jsfiddle.net/pwbo/4ygs2d1t/

This works in a pure JQuery environment. But with Dojo I get this error:

`VM2413:87 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).slick is not a function`

Thanks!

Comment: All you need to do is [load jQuery in noConflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).  Slick appears to reference jQuery via `jQuery` and not `$`, so you should be able to use it.  If you want to use jQuery anywhere, just reference it using the full `jQuery` like so: `jQuery('#selector').doStuff...`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, and jQuery itself seems to work, at least console.debug(jQuery('body').jquery); returns the correct jquery version. But using slick gives me "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).slick is not a function"

Comment: That does not mean that jQuery isn't installed.  It can mean a variety of other problems, including that the selector / element doesn't exist at the time you are attempting to bind slick.

Comment: It could also mean that slick isn't loaded at the time you are attempting to bind it.

Comment: case_b: Sure, your are right. Even more: I know that jQuery is loaded, as I am able to query $(exactly this element).jquery getting the correct version number. I assume, as you are saying, that slick isn't loaded. Do you have an idea how to load it correctly?

Comment: You need to rework on the order of DoJo/jQuery/ and slick related JS files. The one which is taking reference of another should be included at later part. This reordering should fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue today and found a solution for the same.
So, the reason why you get this is because of loading dojo and jquery and slick . So to get rid of this issue load your jquery, then slick and then dojo in your commonheadsection.

thanks
Lijo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somehow we found a solution for this a year ago (not working in this project any more), as far as I remember we managed it to modularize JQuery and Slick correctly, but I am not sure anymore. Thanks anyway!